# June 2013 CU - (2nd release) - The order of installation

Tags: cumulative-update

What should be order of the installation?
As I understand first SharePoint Foundation on servers (Application, 3 WFE)
Then SharePoint Server

Do I need to run PSConfig after the Foundation CU on each server? (Can I install Foundation all the SP servers at the same time and run PSConfig at the same time)?

Do I need to run PSConfig after the SharePoint Server CU on each server? (Can I install SP Server CU all the SP servers at the same time and run PSConfig at the same time)?

What are the correct orders?

Comment: looks like a good link. http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_sustained_engineering/archive/2011/06/29/sharepoint-2010-sp1-and-the-june-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has maintained this as their best practice for SharePoint Foundation,

Install Baseline
Install Service Pack For Foundation that is immediately prior to cumulative update you wish to install
Install Cumulative Updates for Foundation

Since the June 2013 CU is just shy of Service Pack 2, this means:

1) You install SharePoint Foundation
2) You install Service Pack 1 (if not slipstreamed)
3) Install cumulative updates for June 2013

Not sure what you are trying to setup, but you may want to think about just installing Service Pack 2.

EDIT TO ADD: While not specifically mentioned I'm inferring you mean SharePoint Foundation 2010.

EDIT Further: By your comment I'm assuming you're starting from "Zero" that is no farm, no media copied.  You should do this:

1) Install SP 2010 (DO NOT CREATE FARM)
2) Install SP1 (or slipstream with 2010, DO NOT CREATE FARM)
3) Install Cumulative Update
4) Create Farm via PsConfig or your favorite method

If the farm is already going,  after EACH Service Pack or Cumulative update, run 

PSConfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force

So you would install SP1 on all servers (if not already installed), run psconfig as specified above for each server on the farm, then install the CU on all servers, run psconfig again for each server on the farm.

Comment: Okay, I installed Foundation then Server. (Not running SP2. I am going to wait few months before SP2 matures). Do I need to run PSConfig on all the SharePoint Servers? If yes, do I need to run PSConfig 1 server at a time?

Comment: cool. that works. However, I am not installing SP1. I installed SP1 while back. Just installing June 2013 CU (foundation and server).

Comment: PSConfig order - APP server first then other SP Server. one PSConfig at the time so that it does not conflict updating SP Database.  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/05864155-ca87-4687-95b9-d1ca621dd13b/can-i-run-psconfig-parallelly-for-farm-upgrade

Comment: Forgot that last point of one psconfig at a time.  Thanks for reminding me.